# gitab-ci-multi-runner 503 HTTP request failed

Tags: http, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

before writing this I've been looking around but I haven't found anything working for me.

I've been installing gitlab-omnibus and gitlab-ci-multi-runner on centos 6.
Configured with apache, and it seems all to be working fine (I can clone, push repo etc without any problem).

I can register runners and I can see them being picked up by the tools.
But every time I get this error:

```
gitlab-ci-multi-runner 0.6.2 (3227f0a)
Using Shell executor...
stdin: is not a tty
Running on vps.mycompany.uk...

Cloning repository...
Cloning into 'builds/d613c191/0/efesto/testrunner'...
error: The requested URL returned error: 503 Service Temporarily      Unavailable while accessing http://gitlab-ci-    token:xxxxxx@git.mycompany.uk/efesto/testrunner.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed

ERROR: Build failed with: exit status 1
```

here is my apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName git.mycompany.uk
ServerAlias www.git.mycompany.uk
ServerAdmin webmaster@forge.mycompany.uk
UseCanonicalName On
ProxyRequests Off
ServerSignature Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
ProxyPassMatch ^(/[^/]+\.(html|png|ico|css|txt))$ !

ProxyPass /assets !
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8181
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/   
ProxyPassReverse / http://git.mycompany.uk

RewriteEngine on
#Forward these requests to gitlab-git-http-server
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[\w\.-]+/[\w\.-]+/repository/archive [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/v3/projects/.*/repository/archive [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[\w\.-]+/[\w\.-]+/(info/refs|git-upload-pack|git-receive-pack)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.(git)
RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8181%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]

#Forward any other requests to GitLab Rails app (Unicorn)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads
RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,NE]


DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public


#Set up apache error documents, if back end goes down (i.e. 503 error) then a maintenance/deploy page is thrown up.
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 422 /422.html
ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
ErrorDocument 503 /deploy.html

<Directory /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>

<Location />
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

To complete the picture here are the configuration for the gitlab.rb

```
external_url 'http://git.mycompany.uk/'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'gitlab@mycompany.uk'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_reply_to'] = 'noreply@mycompany.uk'
gitlab_rails['omniauth_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['omniauth_allow_single_sign_on'] = false
gitlab_rails['omniauth_block_auto_created_users'] = true

gitlab_git_http_server['enable'] = false
user['username'] = "git"
user['group'] = "git"
user['shell'] = "/bin/sh"
user['home'] = "/var/opt/gitlab"
unicorn['port'] = 8080
nginx['enable'] = false
```

Any idea what could be causing it ?
Thanks.
L.

Comment: checked now and I can happly clone with :

    git clone git@git.mycompany.uk:efesto/testrunner.git

but with 

    git clone http://git.mycopmany.uk/efesto/testrunner.git/


i get

fatal: unable to access 'http://git.mycoompany.uk/efesto/testrunner.git/': The requested URL returned error: 503

Comment: realized is more of an apache config issue.
I'm trying to change according to other posts,

I'm now getting:not valid: is this a git repository?

at least i'm feeling I'm getting closer

Comment: Did you find the solution? Thx

Comment: Hi , yes, I've been reinstalling everything and now seems to be working fine.